# Backup C# Windows application data

Tags: c#, backup

I'm designing a Windows application using C# in Visual Studio. I need to create back up button or something that would back up my data. How do I do that?

Comment: First I think you Should reveal where you are currently storing data. DB ?

Comment: i think that i should save the informations to a SQL file, then i use dumper or something to get the informations back?

Comment: DB which is created by SQL Server

Comment: OK so you have information about employees where?? If it's in a database you could just select everything out and store it as a CSV or the like... If it's stored in a file(s) duplicate it somewhere.

Comment: here is an idea about my DB, the database is employees.sdf, it contains informations about employees, if i install the application and add informations to the software then i uninstall the software on a Computer then the data is lost. how to avoid losing my informations?

Comment: I suggest that you update your question with all the _relevant_ information about your problem. Edit it and add information about your data and the database that you are using for example.

Answer (score 0):

Simlpy create a back up for you data base. I should not be a big problem to triger that proces from your code.

check this sites:

[How to Create Full Database Backup on MS SQL Server for a Database using T-SQL Backup Database command and SqlCmd Utility](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-backup-sql-database-command-line-sqlcmd-sql-batch-file.aspx)

[How to: Create a Full Database Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304.aspx)

Create a new store procedure similar to the content below and call it from your code.

```
Copy Code USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2008R2.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2008R2';
GO
```

Comment: How to create the back up thing?